# Check if there are unfinished task spooler tasks?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, task, zsh

How can I check in shellscript (zsh) whether there are any unfinished task-spooler tasks?

I tried already passing `ts` through grep but am not sure how expandable this would be.

Comment: We could do with having a lot more information. Are we talking the Windows spooler or services that rely on /var/spool i.e mail and print daemons?

Comment: @RamanSailopal the task spooler utility which is accessed via the command `ts`. It's the same one I installed with `brew install task-spooler`

Comment: @RamanSailopal https://www.google.com/search?q=task+spooler

Comment: That's kind of neat - I have not seen it before. Do you mind saying what you find it useful for?

Comment: @MarkSetchell running lots of jobs in the background and being able to track them kind of easily, for example I just converted an entire directory of 40+ `.mov` files into `.mp4` using it. It's more powerful than just that though, pretty sure you can stop and restart terminal and the jobs are still there etc.

Comment: Oh, ok, cool - thank you. I guess it is something I would normally use GNU Parallel for, but I see you can include ordering dependencies, and subsequently add extra jobs after you have started as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ts -l | awk '$2 == "queued" || $2 == "running" { print $0 }'
```

This will take the output of the ts -l command and then check that the second piece of each line equals "queued" or "running" If it does, it will print the line.

You could use

```
ts -l | grep -E '([[:blank:]]+queued[[:blank:]]+) | ([[:blank:]]+running[[:blank:]]+)'
```

This would search the output for multiple blank spaces then the word queued or running and then multiple blank spaces.

Comment: I'd like to match both queued and running, how can I match this?

Comment: I've amended the solution accordingly